# React Redux - Exception thrown by hook while handling onSetChildren

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm having a strange error/warning at a reducer.

If I set "stats" to the action's stats return value I get the error.

```
GET_CUSTOMER_STATS_SUCCESS: (action, state) => ({getCustomerStatsInProgress: false, getCustomerStatsSuccess: true, getCustomerStatsError: false, stats: action.stats}),
```

If I set "stats" to an empty array, everything runs fine.

I already checked that the "action.stats" value is an array. And this action/reducer is equal to any other on my app, but this one is not working. The error message doesn't help at all.

> warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: Exception thrown by hook while handling
>   onSetChildren: Invariant Violation: Expected hook events to fire for
>   the child before its parent includes it in onSetChildren(). Invariant
>   Violation: Expected hook events to fire for the child before its
>   parent includes it in onSetChildren().

Comment: This looks more of a problem with react than redux.

Comment: I know, but as I said the problem seems to be happening at the reducer. If I set stats to [] or event a string, everything goes okay, only if I set it to action.stats (array) the error occurs @vijayst

Comment: It might not be the _reducer_ that is the actual problem, but some component which is using the data the reducer sets.